# Java2dart, how use it

Tags: dart

I have downloaded the sources, then... I don't know what I'm supposed to do.

I think that we have to compile these, but I'm not really familiar with java.

Do you have a complete example for use it ?

Comment: What do you want to achieve with it?

Comment: Just to know how it work. Maybe play with it.

Comment: Please provide the link to source. Is it part of Dart Editor? If so then you probably should follow dart editor build instructions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The java2dart tool was written for Google's own use, to help convert many of the tools from Java into Dart. Is was not intended to support conversion of all Java apps; just what was required to get things like the IDE tools (Analyzer, etc.) into Dart.

As such, there's not a huge amount of info on what it can/can't do or the best way to use it. It is written in Java, and there doesn't appear to be a pre-built binary; so it would almost certainly involve compiling the Java yourself. Unfortunately I have almost zero experience with Java (or fortunately, depending on your point of view :))

You can find a little info on this in the Dart Google Group here:

https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/d/msg/misc/4mSK-M7dm2U/ARbTh6emb-sJ

I wonder whether anyone has tried running java2dart on java2dart to get a nice Dart version? :) Or even then running it through dart2js to get a JavaScript version! ;)